# ASP.NET MVC and @Html.RowFor(x => x.Name) how to add CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Now I have code like:

```
@Html.RowFor(x => x.Name)
```

but I want to ocnvert it to my template like:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Name</label>
<div class="controls">
<input class="input-xlarge focused" id="Name" type="text" value="Name">
</div>
</div>
```

How can I add all the classes?

Comment: Where is `Html.RowFor()` coming from?

Comment: @mxmissile Exactly, what I thought at first? But then, I thought maybe its a control I've never heard of. But on googling it, I couldn't find anything, which suggests me there is no such thing!!

Answer (score 2):

Adding classes can be done like so:

```
@Html.RowFor(x => x.Name, new { @class="control-group other-class" })
```

Answer (score 1):

When making use of razor syntax, you can add html attributes as such:

```
@HtmlSomeControl(x=> x.Whatever, new { id="idNameOfControl", @class="classNameOfControl" })
```

So your code would be essentially become:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class="control-group control-label" )
@Html.DropDownListRowFor(x => x.SelectedCountryId, Model.Country.ViewModel.Countries, new { @class="controls input-xlarge focused")
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thx but I get Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'RowFor' takes 2 arguments

Comment: I'm not sure if @Html.RowFor control exists then (google search doesn't show as well). All razor elements do have extension methods for specifying html attributes.

Comment: Anyway, I've updated my answer considering all you want to show is a label for displaying "Name" property.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="control-group">
@HtmlLabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class="control-label" })
<div class="controls">
 @HtmlTextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new {@class="input-xlarge focused", @id="Name" })
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Down vote? There is no @Html.RowFor...
There is a label and a text box in divs.